# Share data between content types

Tags: 2013, content-type

I currently have a list in SharePoint 2013 with several different content types. One of these content types is listed as manager update which the manager selects to update specific fields for management review in relation to a specific list entry. I am looking for a way to have it when the manager selects the Manager Update content type it will show the new fields for that content type along with the already filled in fields from the list entry (whichever list entry content type was originally chosen). How can I make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd do this by creating site columns for use in your content types. Then in your content type setup, you use the site columns. Then in your list, when you switch content types, the values should persist between the shared fields in the content types.

Comment: Thanks. I Have tried that however none of the fields show up when I change over to the manager update content type.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include *all* of the site columns you use in *every* other content type in the manager update content type.  That way, when you switch the item to being the manager update content type, it will include the columns from whatever content type the item was before, and will show the values originally entered.